# Google Drive SDK - Get presentation's "Present" link

Tags: c#, .net, google-drive-api

I use Google Drive SDK in my .NET application.
I need to get presentation's "Present" link (When open any Google Slides presentation (in edit mode) in Google Drive and click the "Present" - button at the top):

> https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/{DOCUMENT ID}/present#slide=id.p3

So, I use the Files methods (Create, Get, List, etc.) and I thought that in the `Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File.WebViewLink` - property will be the needed link. But the value in the property is

> https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/{DOCUMENT ID}/edit#slide=id.p3

- the edit presentation's link.

*This scenario is for presentations, uploaded from Google Drive's UI, or when use `Create()` method and set `MimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.presentation"` to the new file. I think that the set `MimeType` "convert" the presentation to Google Slides presentation*

If I use `Create()` method, without set the `MimeType` property, the `WebViewLink` property has value `https://drive.google.com/a/CompanyName/file/d/{FILE ID}/view`.

My question is - Is there a way to get Presentation's link in Google Slides ( "https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/{DOCUMENT ID}/present#slide=id.p3" ) from Google Drive API?

Thank you!

Comment: Check this SO question [24815954](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24815954/get-link-to-google-drive-presentation-file) and [15202163](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15202163/get-shared-link-through-google-drive-api?rq=1) if it can help you.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I previewed the topics. But from them I still can't fix my issue... In API v3 (which I use), I should use the `WebViewLink`. In their [API docs](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files), for it wrote `A link for opening the file in a relevant Google editor or viewer in a browser.`. But in that property, the link is always for edit, not for viewing (if it not null).

Any help?

Thank you!