# Fetch Google Drive File path in Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Want to fetch Google Drive File path, by exact **File Name** search with **Extension** and update in other column "Drive File Path"
[image]

```
function onOpen() {
  let menu = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu("Copy Drive Path");
  menu.addItem ("CopyDPath","copypath");
  menu.addToUi();
}
//Copy Drive Path
function copypath() {
  // put your code here, want to search Drive path by searching through EXACT file name with Extension
}
```

[image]

Get Link option looks like this
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
function copypath() {
  const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  var data = sh.getDataRange().getValues()
  data.forEach((d, i) => { try { if (i > 0) d[2] = getPath(d[1]) } catch (e) { } })
  sh.getDataRange().setValues(data)
}
function getPath(fileNameWithExtension) {
  parents = DriveApp.getFileById(getFileId(fileNameWithExtension)).getParents()
  var path
  while (parents.hasNext()) {
    folder = parents.next();
    folderName = folder.getName();
    if (path == null) path = folderName;
    else path = folderName + '/' + path;
    parents = folder.getParents();
  }
  return path
}
function getFileId(name) {
  var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName(name);
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    return (file.getId())
  }
}
```

### references

[searchFiles()](https://searchFiles)

[getParents()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getparents)

[hasNext()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file-iterator#hasnext)

### edit

to get a clickable link, try

```
function copypath() {
  const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  var data = sh.getDataRange().getValues()
  data.forEach((d, i) => {
    try {
      if (i > 0) {
        var parents = DriveApp.getFileById(getFileId(d[1])).getParents()
        while (parents.hasNext()) {
          folder = parents.next();
          d[2] = folder.getUrl();
        }
      }
    } catch (e) { }
  })
  sh.getDataRange().setValues(data)
}
function getFileId(name) {
  var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName(name);
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    return (file.getId())
  }
}
```

### edit2

to retrieve the link for each file

```
function clickableLink() {
  const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  var data = sh.getDataRange().getValues()
  data.forEach((d, i) => {
    try {
      if (i > 0) {
          d[2] = getFileUrl(d[1]);
      }
    } catch (e) { }
  })
  sh.getDataRange().setValues(data)
}
function getFileUrl(name) {
  var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName(name);
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    return (file.getUrl())
  }
}
```

Comment: Dear Mike, it's working like a charm, can you please edit and replace with **Drive File Path** with **Drive Get Link**. I want the Drive links which is clickable and redirect to mentioned specific folder.

Comment: Mike, it's getting URL of the folder space `https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0ALk-BTQql64HUk9PVA` but I want the **Get Link** which appears after RightClick_on_Folder > Get Link and looks like this `https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/0B7k-BTQql64HQWRGNEQ0OFdteW8/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=111630109296082365643&resourcekey=0-TvpU9EL7DIVLSy9CYV3Okg&rtpof=true&sd=true)`

Comment: sorry, but when I right_click on a folder, I got `https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/18akqHAN7PSPMnG3h5HpCskQsMCv4TqCM?usp=sharing` , There is not a method to get presentation URL according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24815954/get-link-to-google-drive-presentation-file

Comment: you can get that link for pptx for instance, not for folder.

Comment: OK as per you it won't work on PPT so please make it happen for PDF and its Get Link is `https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7k-BTQql64HVDg4OWwyWW5IMnJScld3ZF9tN0VKRkhveENv/view?usp=sharing&resourcekey=0--WrqOBJAAjk-W8QM7cuP6A` .. and I'm also attaching a image file for your reference that where you can see the **Get Link** option please check in the Question Option.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244571/discussion-between-joseph-john-and-mike-steelson).

Comment: Then @Mike if I want to switch **columns B (File Name) to some D-E Column** and **Column C (Gel Link) to some J-K Column** , then which value I have to toggle for correct output

Comment: file name is d[1] (means column B), change 1 as necessary (A=0, B=1, ... D=3, E=4) | link is now in d[2] (means column C) change according to your choice (J=9, K=10)

Answer (score 2):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to search the files using an extension like `.pdf`.
- You want to retrieve the filenames and the file path on Google Drive.
- You want to put them in the columns "B" and "C".
- Your files are existing in your Google Drive.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

### Usage:

In this sample script, a Google Apps Script library is used.

#### 1. Install Google Apps Script library.

Please install [FilesApp](https://github.com/tanaikech/FilesApp) Google Apps Script library. You can see the method for installing it at [here](https://github.com/tanaikech/FilesApp#how-to-install).

#### 2. Enable Drive API.

[Please enable Drive API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

#### 2. Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Spreadsheet and set your sheet name and save the script.

```js
function copypath() {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set the sheet name.
  const extension = ".pdf"; // Please set the extension you expect.

  // 1. Retrieve folder structure from Google Drive.
  const res = FilesApp.getAllFoldersInFolder("root");
  const obj = res.name.reduce((o, e) => (o[e[e.length - 1]] = e.join("/"), o), {});

  // 2. Retrieve files by an extension and create an array for putting to Spreadsheet.
  const files = DriveApp.searchFiles(`title contains '${extension}' and trashed=false`); // or const files = DriveApp.searchFiles(`mimeType='application/pdf' and trashed=false`);
  const values = [];
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    const file = files.next();
    const filename = file.getName();
    if (filename.slice(-4).toLowerCase() == extension) {
      const parent = file.getParents();
      values.push([filename, obj[parent.hasNext() ? parent.next().getName() : ""] || "No parent"]);
    }
  }

  // 3. Put the array to Spreadsheet.
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  sheet.getRange(2, 2, values.length, 2).setValues(values);
}
```

- When this script is run, the following flow is run.

  1. Retrieve folder structure from Google Drive.

     - Here, FilesApp of Google Apps Script library is used.
  2. Retrieve files by an extension and create an array for putting into Spreadsheet.
  3. Put the array on Spreadsheet.

     - The retrieved values are put to the columns "B" and "C".
- If you want to retrieve the PDF file, you can also use `` const files = DriveApp.searchFiles(`mimeType='application/pdf' and trashed=false`); `` instead of `` const files = DriveApp.searchFiles(`title contains '${extension}' and trashed=false`); ``.

### Note:

- This is a simple sample script. So, please modify this for your actual situation.

### References:

- [FilesApp of Google Apps Script library](https://github.com/tanaikech/FilesApp)
- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

### Added:

From your reply,

> No, this is not what I want. What I want is extract file path through File Name Search

If you want to retrieve the filenames from the column "B" of Spreadsheet and retrieve the file path, and want to put the file path to the column "C" of the Spreadsheet, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function sample2() {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set the sheet name.

  // 1. Retrieve folder structure from Google Drive.
  const res = FilesApp.getAllFoldersInFolder("root");
  const obj = res.name.reduce((o, e) => (o[e[e.length - 1]] = e.join("/"), o), {});

  // 2. Retrieve filenames from Spreasheet.
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const range = sheet.getRange("B2:B" + sheet.getLastRow());

  // 3. Retrieve the file path and create an array for putting to Spreadsheet.
  const values = range.getValues().map(filename => {
    const file = DriveApp.getFilesByName(filename);
    if (file.hasNext()) {
      const parent = file.next().getParents();
      return [obj[parent.hasNext() ? parent.next().getName() : ""] || "No parent"];
    }
    return ["File was not found."];
  });

  // 4. Put the array to Spreadsheet.
  range.offset(0, 1).setValues(values);
}
```

Comment: No, this is not what I want. What I want is extract file path through **File Name Search**

Comment: @Joseph John Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. From `No, this is not what I want. What I want is extract file path through File Name Search`, my proposed script searches the filenames and the file path of the filenames are put to the Spreadsheet. But, if you wanted to retrieve the filenames from the column "B" of Spreadsheet and retrieve the file path, and want to put the file path to the column "C" of the Spreadsheet, I added the sample script in my answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misundetstood your question, I apologize again.